# Implementing android chart using MPChart library

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am trying to implement pie chart, and I keep getting no chart data available. I am using the library MPAndroidChart, I liked the design of it and the demo part. I am copying this code, and its not working. I don't want any seekbar in my app, please help me to get along with this library. Thank you.

Of course, consider my activity implements OnChartValueSelectedListener

```
private PieChart mChart;
private Typeface tf;
protected String[] mMonths = new String[] {
        "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec"
};
protected String[] mParties = new String[] {
        "Party A", "Party B", "Party C", "Party D", "Party E", "Party F", "Party G", "Party H",
        "Party I", "Party J", "Party K", "Party L", "Party M", "Party N", "Party O", "Party P",
        "Party Q", "Party R", "Party S", "Party T", "Party U", "Party V", "Party W", "Party X",
        "Party Y", "Party Z"
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.piechart);
PieChart mChart = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.chart1);
        mChart.setUsePercentValues(true);
        mChart.setDescription("");
        mChart.setExtraOffsets(5, 10, 5, 5);
        mChart.setDragDecelerationFrictionCoef(0.95f);
         tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "OpenSans-Regular.ttf");            mChart.setCenterTextTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "OpenSans-Light.ttf"));
        mChart.setCenterText(generateCenterSpannableText());
        mChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
        mChart.setHoleColor(Color.WHITE);
        mChart.setTransparentCircleColor(Color.WHITE);
        mChart.setTransparentCircleAlpha(110);
        mChart.setHoleRadius(58f);
        mChart.setTransparentCircleRadius(61f);
        mChart.setDrawCenterText(true);
        mChart.setRotationAngle(0);
        // enable rotation of the chart by touch
        mChart.setRotationEnabled(true);
        mChart.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(true);
        // mChart.setUnit(" €");
        // mChart.setDrawUnitsInChart(true);
        // add a selection listener
        mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);
        setData(3, 100);
        mChart.animateY(1400, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInOutQuad);
        // mChart.spin(2000, 0, 360);
        Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
        l.setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.RIGHT_OF_CHART);
        l.setXEntrySpace(7f);
        l.setYEntrySpace(0f);
        l.setYOffset(0f);
  }
  private void setData(int count, float range) {
    float mult = range;
    ArrayList<Entry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    // IMPORTANT: In a PieChart, no values (Entry) should have the same
    // xIndex (even if from different DataSets), since no values can be
    // drawn above each other.
    for (int i = 0; i < count + 1; i++) {
        yVals1.add(new Entry((float) (Math.random() * mult) + mult / 5, i));
    }
    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < count + 1; i++)
        xVals.add(mParties[i % mParties.length]);
    PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yVals1, "Election Results");
    dataSet.setSliceSpace(3f);
    dataSet.setSelectionShift(5f);
    // add a lot of colors
    ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int c : ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);
    for (int c : ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);
    for (int c : ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);
    for (int c : ColorTemplate.LIBERTY_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);
    for (int c : ColorTemplate.PASTEL_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);
    colors.add(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
    dataSet.setColors(colors);
    //dataSet.setSelectionShift(0f);
    PieData data = new PieData(xVals, dataSet);
    data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());
    data.setValueTextSize(11f);
    data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    data.setValueTypeface(tf);
    mChart.setData(data);
    // undo all highlights
    mChart.highlightValues(null);
    mChart.invalidate();
}
private SpannableString generateCenterSpannableText() {
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString("MPAndroidChart\ndeveloped by Philipp Jahoda");
    s.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.7f), 0, 14, 0);
    s.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL), 14, s.length() - 15, 0);
    s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GRAY), 14, s.length() - 15, 0);
    s.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(.8f), 14, s.length() - 15, 0);
    s.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), s.length() - 14, s.length(), 0);
    s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue()), s.length() - 14, s.length(), 0);
    return s;
}
@Override
public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {
    if (e == null)
        return;
    Log.i("VAL SELECTED",
            "Value: " + e.getVal() + ", xIndex: " + e.getXIndex()
                    + ", DataSet index: " + dataSetIndex);
}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected() {
    Log.i("PieChart", "nothing selected");
}
```

Edit: My Issue is with this line Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "OpenSans-Regular.ttf");  its giving me addFontFromAsset failed to create font OpenSans-Regular.ttf
Despite it works for me when i use this InputStream am = getAssets().open("cert.pem");

Comment: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/tree/master/MPChartExample/assets this is library, removing the create from asset worked, think there is error in the .ttf files